# How to apply box shadow on a div when input element inside it is focused

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I have created a custom input element with increment and decrement button inside a parent div.
I want to apply a box shadow on the parent div when the input element is in focus and not when the increment and decrement arrow are clicked.
Code is something like

```
<div className='parent'>
   <input type='number' onChange={onChange}>
   <div className='arrow-btns'>
       <Increment/>
       <Decrement/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure React based solution, you can:

1. Create a boolean state `focused` that represents whether the input is focused or not
2. Make a style object with box shadow that's set based on that state
3. Set that style for the parent
4. Use `onFocus` and `onBlur` events on the input to set the state

Since we used a state, the component will re-render when it's changed, so it'll set the box shadow value accordingly:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Increment = () => <button>Increment</button>
const Decrement = () => <button>Decrement</button>

function App() {
   const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
   
   const style = {
     width: '200px',
     height: '90px',
     boxShadow: focused? '0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' : 'none'
   }
   
   const setToFocused = () => setFocused(true);
   const setToUnfocused = () => setFocused(false);
   
  return (
    <div className='parent' style={style}>
      <input type='number' onFocus={setToFocused} onBlur={setToUnfocused}></input>
        <Increment/>
        <Decrement/>
   </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

It's also good to separate the intents of the style objects, where one is the base style and the other depends on the state. Then just merge them:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Increment = () => <button>Increment</button>
const Decrement = () => <button>Decrement</button>

function App() {
   const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
   
   const baseStyle = {
     width: '200px',
     height: '90px'
   }
   
   const focusedStyle = focused 
   ? { boxShadow: '0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' } 
   : {}
   
   const style = {...baseStyle, ...focusedStyle}
   
   const setToFocused = () => setFocused(true);
   const setToUnfocused = () => setFocused(false);
   
  return (
    <div className='parent' style={style}>
      <input type='number' onFocus={setToFocused} onBlur={setToUnfocused}></input>
        <Increment/>
        <Decrement/>
   </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus` and `blur` event on the input, and `add` and `remove` the `placeholder` class which apply the box shadow on the parent by `input.parentNode.classList.add('placeholder')` and input.parentNode.classList.remove('placeholder')

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  input.parentNode.classList.add('placeholder')
})

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  input.parentNode.classList.remove('placeholder')
})
```

```css
.placeholder {
    box-shadow: 2px 3px #888888;

}
```

```html
<div className='parent'>
   <input id="input" type='number' onChange={onChange}>
   <div className='arrow-btns'>
       <Increment/>
       <Decrement/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:has` selector.

```
.parent:has(input:focus) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 7px 31px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
  -moz-box-shadow: -4px 7px 31px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
  box-shadow: -4px 7px 31px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
}
```

Please note that few browsers are yet to support it and once they do, this'll be a simple solution for your use case. You can read more about it here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Somehow this dosen't work :/

Comment: Which browser did you try it on?